# MongoDB - Group by customer and retrieve documents with maximum price

Tags: mongodb

Consider having these objects in `db.invoices`

```
{ "customer" : "john", "price" : 4, "weekday": "WED" }
{ "customer" : "john", "price" : 8, "weekday": "SUN" }
{ "customer" : "john", "price" : 6, "weekday": "SAT" }
{ "customer" : "john", "price" : 5, "weekday": "SUN" }    
{ "customer" : "bob", "price" : 10, "weekday": "SAT" }
{ "customer" : "bob", "price" : 15, "weekday": "MON" }
```

How can I query for documents having the maximum price for each customer? For above sample:

```
[ {
  "customer": "bob",
  "price": 15,
  "weekday": "MON"
}, {
  "customer": "john",
  "price": 8,
  "weekday": "SUN"
} ]
```

I can't figure it out using aggregation framework.

Edit 1: Problem is getting `weekday`s along with customer names. I do not want the maximum price alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to include `weekday` you need to pre-sort the docs to put the doc you want from each group first and then use `$group` with `$first`:

```js
db.invoices.aggregate([
    {$sort: {customer: 1, price: -1}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$customer',
        price: {$first: '$price'},
        weekday: {$first: '$weekday'}
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to include all other fields other than naming each one in group operation?

Comment: there is, but only if you know the names of the fields you want to include - there isn't a way to include "the rest of the fields" in general.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the result you want, it's one of several:

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
    {$project: {customer: 1, other:{ price: "$price", weekday: "$weekday"}}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$customer',
        max: {$max: '$other'}
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_group) operator:

```
db.invoises.aggregate([
  { $group : { _id: '$customer', price: { $max: '$price' } } }
])
```

Comment: That does not give `weekday`s to me! That's the problem